# Error in HOG descriptor

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am using HOG descriptor for feature extraction. I am using visual studio 2012 and opencv 2.4.9 version. I am getting run time error in hog.compute function.

```
int main()
{
     Mat img_raw = imread("p1.jpg", 1); // load as color image.    
     Mat img;
     cvtColor(img_raw, img, CV_RGB2GRAY);

     HOGDescriptor hog;
     vector<float> descriptor;
     vector<Point>locations;

     hog.compute(img, descriptor,Size(32,32),Size(0,0),locations);   

     cout << "HOG descriptor size is " << hog.getDescriptorSize() << endl;
     cout << "img dimensions: " << img.cols << " width x " << img.rows <<     "height" << endl;
     cout << "Found " << descriptor.size() << " descriptor values" << endl;
     cout << "Nr of locations specified : " << locations.size() << endl;
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Plz include run time error as well, so we could have better visual over problem.

Comment: Also, be aware that OpenCv loads color images as BGR, so you should use `CV_BGR2GRAY`, although it probably doesn't make much difference

Comment: Thanks... I made that change regarding BGR but i have same error and error is-"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDA4224E7B (msvcr110d.dll) in HOG.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"

Comment: By adding this file "opencv_features2d249d.lib" I got correct output.   Thanks everyone.